# Why color css rule is not being applied on button element when changing from disabled to enabled on Safari 14+ alike browsers

Tags: css, ios, material-ui, webkit

Some frontend form validation code is changing disabled attribute of a submit button in a form.

For the 2 states (enabled/disabled), they are different css rules applied, one of these is the text color of the button element.

Something that looks like a bug is happening on Safari/Webkit based browser **in version 14+ only**. **The bug is not present on previous safari versions for instance**.

The text of the button stays greyed out even after the button being enabled and color rules is updated in CSS rules. In the Devtools, computed property shows the proper color value (see screenshots), but it is not being applied by the browser.

Is this a known issue?

*Note: I am using material-UI framework, which means there are some extra layers of code which interfere and makes it difficult to post a simplified sample of code.
But since it is only happening on specific platforms, my guess is that material-ui does not play any role in the root cause.*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a bug in Safari, affecting version 14.1 to 14.6.
It is fixed since version 14.7.

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/18280#issuecomment-875843010) for the root cause.

Some more insight [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26251#issuecomment-867109199) too.